# Why Phoenix / Elixir / Erlang crashed?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

It's not Out of Memory error, don't know why else it could crash. The `erl_crash.dump` says:

```
Slogan: Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,myapp,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Myapp.Endpoint',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Phoenix.Endp
System version: Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source-d2a6d81] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Compiled: Mon Mar 14 19:34:48 2016
Taints: crypto
Atoms: 15257
Calling Thread: scheduler:1
```

The App itself did couple of millions short string compression using zlib (from OTP) in a single process.

Below couple of screens from Erlang Dump Viewer

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says: the app couldn't start `Elixir.Myapp.Endpoint`. In the case of the endpoint the most common reason is that something already listens on that port (another instance of the same app maybe?). Specifics will vary depending on the exact reason why a particular OTP process cannot start correctly.